# How can I use a dictionary to replace 2 strings that are being compared?

Tags: c#

```
string[] UserCodes = { "admin", "testcode" };
string[] UserWords = { "123", "testword" };

public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < UserCodes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (UserCode.Text.Equals(UserCodes[i])  && UserWord.Text.Equals(UserWords[i]))
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Something Went Wrong", "Incorrect Password or Username", "Try Again");
        }
    }         
}
```

Right now I am using 2 separate, but conjunct strings, which I am comparing to user input to determine whether or not they entered the correct login credentials.

```
public void d(string[] args)
  
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> LogCred = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        LogCred.Add("admin", "123");
        LogCred.Add("testcode", "test");

    }
```

This is the dictionary I tried to make.

My question is how can I use a dictionary to acomplish the same results?

Comment: Hopefully this is a toy app and not a real application, since you should NEVER be comparing clear-text credentials, nor have access to them in the first place. Assuming that is the case, what is the relationship between these arrays? Does index 0 in each array correlate?

Comment: Unfortunate reality is that if you read about using Dictionary in C# and still have no idea how to store mapping of string to string in one I don't think SO answer can help you either... Showing your attempts to use Dictionary may help with figuring out where your problem to understand Dictionary is...

Comment: Yes, each index of both the arrays correlate to the same credentials, so you would need UserCodes[0] and UserWords[0] to enter. I am designing this app for my internal assesment, and even if I did develop it further to be of actual use, me having access to the credentials would not matter as theres no sensitive information involved. The "idea" was to hand out both passwords and usernames to each user, and not have them designate their own passwords. I hope this clears up the purpose :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a test app, and putting aside security for now, you can initialize a Dictionary with the username/password combinations.  I'm a bit confused on `Code` vs `Word`, but this is jist of it:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> users = new Dictionary<string, string>
 {
   //['code']  = 'word'  
     ["admin"] = "123",
     ["testcode"] = "testword"
 };
```

Then you can use LINQ to see if any of the combos match the user input:

```
public static void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == UserCode.Text && x.Value == UserWord.Text);

    if(user != null)
    {
         //got a match
    }
    else 
    {
        //no matches
    }
}
```

Note the comparison is expecting the casing to match as well, as it's written.

Comment: Any particular reason to troll the OP with such "usage" of a Dictionary?

Comment: Because learning to code is an incremental learning process.  You don't build your first winforms app with a database and parameterized sql when you are still learning general C# syntax.   OP has shown effort in their question and is not just looking for a handout.  I swear the attitude on this site bums me out sometimes.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I don’t know what Alexei’s intent was, but at the very least if you want to educate the OP on dictionary use, you should do key based lookups and then compare the value, rather than iterating unnecessarily. Otherwise they might as well just use a List<KeyValuePair>.